# Integration testing without Spring context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, spring-boot-test

Should I always start Spring context during integration tests? (I mean using `@SpringBootTest` annotation)

Currently I'm writing integration test that involves a few classes and in order to make it faster I create object graph *by hand* (i.e. I don't start Spring IoC container). So currently my integration test (written in Spock) looks like this:

```
class UserConverterIT extends Specification {

    UserConverter converter = new UserConverter(new UserDtoFactory(new UserGroupPolicy()))

    def 'should ...'() {
        when:
        converter.convert(...)

        then:
        ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively I could add `@SpringBootTest` annotation, put `@Autowire` above `UserConverter` field and all dependecies would be injected automatically. However, the first approach is much faster. Is there something wrong in this approach?

Answer (score 0):

As you said the `@Autowired` annotation would inject all dependencies and load the whole context automatically. Your approach is also working but its really fragile!
How can you guarantee that in your tests you never need some beans which you didn't manually new them?

Also there is another important thing. When you let the spring to inject the dependencies, if there is a problem on declaring the beans, problem would show on test phase, but in your approach they won't identify.

Also you might sometimes `@Autowired` an interface which told spring to get the implementation on runtime. For example you have a parent module which has an interface that implements in the child module. When you want to write a test case in parent you don't have access to child implementation to make new of that.

Comment: "How can you guarantee that in your tests you never need some beans which you didn't manually new them?" I use only constructor injection so I need to provide all dependencies via constructor. If I miss any required bean my code simply won't compile.

Comment: @k13i If you use only constructor injection in whole your application, so you won't face any problems. Also I updated my answer with another problem in your approach. Totally as I said it works but its fragile and suggested to avoid.

Comment: "When you let the spring to inject the dependencies, if there is a problem on declaring the beans, problem would show on test phase, but in your approach they won't identify." I agree, but my question was "Should I ALWAYS start Spring context during integration tests?". I do have tests that start Spring context and they discover problems with bean declaration and so on. I just have SOME integration tests that run withouth Spring context